# module.exports: is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Following is my sqlhelper.js

```
var req = require("request");
var tp = require('tedious-promises');
var dbConfig = require('../config/connectionString.json');
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

function SQLHelper() {
}

SQLHelper.prototype.ExecuteDataset = function(query, params, callback, failure) {

    tp.setConnectionConfig(dbConfig);
    tp.sql(q);
    $(params).each(function(idx) {
        var p = params[idx];
        tp.parameter(p.name, p.value);
    });

    tp.execute()
        .then(function(results) {
            callback(results)
        }).fail(function(err) {
            failure(err);
        });
};

module.exports = SQLHelper;
```

I have used it like this

```
var sqlHelper = require('../SQLHelper.js');
sqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(q, params, function(results) {//Here I get error
                console.log(results)
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

I get following error **TypeError: sqlHelper.ExecuteDataset is not a function**

I dont know whats wrong here.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an instance of `SQLHelper` before it will have the prototype methods.  Prototype properties are available on an instance of the object, not on the constructor.

If you want a singleton (only one object that every one shares), you can do this:

```
// export an instance of our object
module.exports = new SQLHelper();
```

Or, if you want a separate object each time you use it, you can change where you use it to this:

```
// load module and create an instance
let sqlHelper = new (require('../SQLHelper.js'))();
```

---

Or, if you don't actually have any instance data and you just want to use a namespace, you can do this:

```
let SQLHelper = {};
SQLHelper.ExecuteDataset  = ...

module.exports = SQLHelper;
```